# JS / Flow: unresolved type $ReadOnlyArray

Tags: javascript, eslint, flowtype, eslintrc

I'm trying to get the IDE to recognize Flow native types, but with no success.

I have ESLint installed on my project. Not sure why Flow isn't able to parse them.

All my node modules are latest.

Here's a portion of what my .eslintrc.json looks like:

```
{
 "env": {
  "es6": true,
  "node": true
 },
 "extends": ["eslint:recommended"],
 "globals": {
  "$ReadOnlyArray": true,
 },
 "parser": "babel-eslint",
 "plugins": [
  "babel",
  "flowtype"
 ]
}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using Intellij Idea.

Comment: So you've got this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/flow.html, but only for Ultimate Edition. If you don't have one I suggest you start using Visual Studio Code and install Flow Language Support plugin :P.

Comment: Yup I've followed everything there. I've been using Flow for a while before I realized there are undocumented natives like Class and $ReadOnlyArray.

https://www.saltycrane.com/flow-type-cheat-sheet/latest/

I figured I must have configured something wrongly, but can't figure out what went wrong.